# How to set default value in html for <select> element using Laravel

Tags: html, laravel-8, html-select

I am able to sort the list from my dropdown but the issue is how to set the default selection from the dropdown,
The drop-down list correctly  populated the right data from the database

**In Html(blade file)**

```
<select name="cty" id="country" class="form-control" required>
  <option selected hidden></option>
    @foreach ($countries as $c)
      <option  value="{{ $c->id }}"> {{ $c->name }} </option>
    @endforeach
 </select>
```

**In  js files**

```
function NASort(a, b) {
            if (a.innerHTML == 'NA') {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (b.innerHTML == 'NA') {
                return -1;
            }
            return (a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML) ? 1 : -1;
        };
   
    $('#country option').sort(NASort).appendTo('#country');
 
    $('#country option:eq(-1)').insertBefore('#country option:eq(1)');
```

Comment: "_how to set the default selection_" What is the default selection?

Comment: @brombeer currently, default selection was selected from the back  , i mean if value -a,b,c,d -  value d was selected as default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select name="cty" id="country" class="form-control" required>
    @foreach ($countries as $c)
      <option  value="{{ $c->id }}" {{ $c->id == 3  ? 'selected' : '' }}> {{ $c->name }} </option>
    @endforeach
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<option value="{{ $c->id  }}" {{ $countries->country_id == $c->id  ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $category->name }}</option>
```

Comment: _Why_ should OP try this? What does it do? What is `$countries->country_id`? Please add a little explanation

Comment: the question details is incomplete.but i think he wnats to set default item that match to $c->id

Comment: @mostafafaryabi check my comments above